# "Sagemaker Notebook with Interactive Session -- Install packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

We have followed this doc to spin up notebook running with interactive sessions. We want to add a few python packages to the environment to assist with development (i.e. pyright). I have added the pip install at the bottom, stopped the instance, restart instance, run "import pyright", but I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyright'"

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
 
ANACONDA_DIR=/home/ec2-user/anaconda3
 
# Create and Activate Conda Env
echo "Creating glue_pyspark conda enviornment"
conda create --name glue_pyspark python=3.7 ipykernel jupyter nb_conda -y
 
echo "Activating glue_pyspark"
source activate glue_pyspark
 
# Install Glue Sessions to Env
echo "Installing AWS Glue Sessions with pip"
pip install aws-glue-sessions
 
# Clone glue_pyspark to glue_scala. This is required because I had to match kernel naming conventions to their environments and couldn't have two kernels in one conda env. 
echo "Cloning glue_pyspark to glue_scala"
conda create --name glue_scala --clone glue_pyspark
 
# Remove python3 kernel from glue_pyspark
rm -r ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_pyspark/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
rm -r ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_scala/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
 
# Copy kernels to Jupyter kernel env (Discoverable by conda_nb_kernel)
echo "Copying Glue PySpark Kernel"
cp -r ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_pyspark/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel/glue_pyspark/ ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_pyspark/share/jupyter/kernels/glue_pyspark/
 
echo "Copying Glue Spark Kernel"
mkdir ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_scala/share/jupyter/kernels
cp -r ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_scala/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel/glue_spark/ ${ANACONDA_DIR}/envs/glue_scala/share/jupyter/kernels/glue_spark/
 
echo "Changing Jupyter kernel manager from EnvironmentKernelSpecManager to CondaKernelSpecManager"
JUPYTER_CONFIG=/home/ec2-user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
 
sed -i '/EnvironmentKernelSpecManager/ s/^/#/' ${JUPYTER_CONFIG}
echo "c.CondaKernelSpecManager.name_format='conda_{environment}'" >> ${JUPYTER_CONFIG}
echo "c.CondaKernelSpecManager.env_filter='anaconda3$|JupyterSystemEnv$|/R$'" >> ${JUPYTER_CONFIG}

# Install python modules to env
pip install "pyright"
EOF
systemctl restart jupyter-server
```

Am I missing something in the script? I assumed just "pip install "pyright"" would've worked.

Update:
I have included the following under the pip install aws-glue-sessions:

> pip install "pyright"
> and
> pip install pyright

When I check the CloudWatch logs, I see that the package is being downloaded... I would assume it means it's installed.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeKce.png

Comment: can you add it to existing pip install aws-glue-sessions pyright and try again?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I have tried that as well. It did not work. Which I find odd because when I check the LifecycleConfigOnStart log in CloudWatch, I see that it has been installed (I included a screenshot in an updated post)

Comment: @TechNewbie Can you do a pip list from your notebook? I have the pyright package installed, looks like I can't import, rather run the tool from command line (ref: [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright#command-line)).

Comment: @durga_sury You are right. I did notice this is not an import type of package after the fact. :)